# Swift - Nested Table View - didSelectRowAt() never called for Inner Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, segue

I have nested Table Views, Outer and Inner Table View. Both table views show up as expected.

Next step is to click on the Inner table view cell, and segue to next Scene. I created segues dn CTRL + drag from Inner table view cell to next Scene. This does not work, Inner table View does not call selectRowAt index tableView().

I have (with no effect) both set to true:

```
 tableView.allowsSelection = true
 tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

Basically I just deque cells and generate the two Table views, and then try to get some functionality in Inner table view by:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {       
      if tableView.tag == 2  //this is inner table view
      {
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "Chart", sender: nil)
      }
   }
```

Should I use delegation instead, or is there some other method? Why do Inner table view cells not trigger didSelectRowAt index method to execute? I wonder why Inner table view behaves like this with no reaction to tap? 
I understand inner table view is subview of outer table view, but I do not know why it does not work. I tried to programatically select cell of Inner Table View but that did not work as well.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "nested tableviews"? Do you have table views as subviews of `UITableViewCell`s of another table view?

Comment: I assume you set the delegate on both `TableViews`?

Comment: Exactly, I dragged Table View(Inner) inside other table views(Outer) Cell. Inner table view shows up ok, but does nothing. Nothing happens once it is clicked  although I have segue from this Inner table view to next scene.

Comment: Yes they both share same delegate, same View Controller, I differentiate between them using tags. This is how the both display as expected. But when I click on the inner table view cell, although he has selectRowAt index fund set it does nothing. I guess it has something to do with view hierarchy, but I do not know what...

Comment: Set the delegate of the inner tableview to the outer table view cell class and you will get all the delegate methods invoked.

Comment: @good4pc Thanks. I have set inner table view delegate to be outer table view but it is still the same. Both table views show up nicely, but nothing happens after tapping either one of table views(Outer and Inner).  I was not able to set inner table view delegate to outer table view cell, just to outer table view.

Comment: @Bosniak Share a sample project which replicates the issue.